# Importing old git projects to Gerrit

Tags: git, commit, gerrit

I am trying to install gerrit over our git repositories. We have lots of projects that saved in git repositories. After installations everything seems ok from web interface. I can see the projects from admin>projects menu. I can add users or groups to gerrit. But if I want to add access rules to project when I click on Access link from admin menu server returns Application Error, Server Error(Internal Server Error).

If I change any settings from general tab of admin menu I can pass this error but this time I cannot commit my changes to my git server.

Full trace of error log is like this;

> > [2011-06-10 10:36:20,111] WARN  / : Error in projectAccess
> >     java.lang.NullPointerException
> >             at com.google.gerrit.server.git.VersionedMetaData.getRevision(VersionedMetaData.java:69)
> >             at com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.project.ProjectAccessFactory.call(ProjectAccessFactory.java:92)
> >             at com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.project.ProjectAccessFactory.call(ProjectAccessFactory.java:40)
> >             at com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.Handler.to(Handler.java:65)
> >             at com.google.gerrit.httpd.rpc.project.ProjectAdminServiceImpl.projectAccess(ProjectAdminServiceImpl.java:75)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
> >             at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.MethodHandle.invoke(MethodHandle.java:91)
> >             at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.JsonServlet.doService(JsonServlet.java:382)
> >             at com.google.gwtjsonrpc.server.JsonServlet.service(JsonServlet.java:268)
> >             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:216)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:141)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:93)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:63)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.gwtexpui.server.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:129)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:134)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.gerrit.httpd.RequestCleanupFilter.doFilter(RequestCleanupFilter.java:54)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:129)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:59)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:122)
> >             at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:110)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1322)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:473)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:921)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:403)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:856)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:59)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:114)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:352)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:1069)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:805)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:510)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.access$000(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:34)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
> >             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:450)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Edit: Changed back to stable version everything went ok.

Answer (score 2):

We use following schema to add old project to gerrit, works perfect:

1. Create fresh project in your gerrit.
2. Open your git repository.
3. `git remote add` your gerrit repository.
4. `git push remote_name master:refs/heads/master` (same for other branches if you have).